# JavaScript or jQuery dynamically show form input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry if this is a daft question, but if I display a text input field, say your_age in a table cell, then want to dynamically display what the user inputs in the table cell next to it, how would I do that in JavaScript/jQuery?

For example if I enter `100` I want the table cell next to the input field to display `100` without the need to click a submit button.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: You are looking for the `onKeyUp` event.  Basically every time a key is released it will fire some bit of JavaScript that can do whatever you want.

Comment: Have you analyzed your layout in terms of UX, why do you need to repeat what the user is entering in the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#myField').on('keyup', function() {
    $('#myTableCell').text($(this).val());
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/seancannon/K8qZ9/7/

Comment: `.text()` is usually more appropriate for user input (or any input at all)

Comment: What good would docs do here? Type `<script>alert("asdf")` and it alerts that immediately. `.html()` opens up that vulnerability, while `.text()` does not. If you're not expecting HTML, don't use it

Comment: Another daft question but how can I multiply the value by 0.6 before displaying it beneath the field. I've tried  $('#myTableCell').html($(this).val()x0.6); but that didn't work! Sorry complete beginner.

Comment: @Ian agree, this is begging for second-order XSS.. I must punish with a downvote

Comment: Wow so instead of clicking "edit" and changing "val" to "text" I get 3 downvotes? Spaz much, it's the client-side. The user would be hacking his own client, way to think that one through. Also, way to give away that you have multiple accounts.

Comment: @AlienWebguy Wow so instead of being reasonable, you assume all that? I never downvoted, I have **1** account and would never resort to spam downvoting, and no one spazzed. I just upvoted to help. Or is that just my 4th account? Anyways, "his own client" means nothing; the server is reachable from the client, which isn't "his".

Comment: I was talking to Esailija :) Anyway my point stands. Putting .val() in the table isn't an XSS threat at all and would only inconvenience the user entering the HTML.

Comment: @AlienWebguy I edited the answer to show what I meant (since textboxes don't return anything for `.text()`). Maybe I'm missing something, but the user could enter `<script>$.ajax({url: "/products/delete/", data: { id: 1 }, type: "POST" });</script>`, and whether or not product id 1 is related to the user, it *could* be deleted. I'm just saying. I never use `.html()` when dealing with setting something's inner content (not `.value`). At the same time, it could be very well regulated (maybe not using `keyup`, but `change`) and cleaned so "bad" things couldn't be included (like script tags)

Comment: The user could add that in the console too man. XSS is prevented on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `.change()`

```
<input type="text" id="txt_name"  />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#txt_name").change(function(){
        var blah = $(this).val();
        $('#id_of_cell').val(blah);
    });
})
</script>
```

Comment: That won't reflect new text until the field is blurred.

Comment: @AlienWebguy that's right. Your answer is the correct one. Will leave the erroneous answer here anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#input1').keyup(function() {
 $('#input2').val($(this).val());
});
```